# jquery getting data from data-href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a table row a link by using jQuery and this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
    });
});
```

In my html file i have this:

```
<tr class='clickable-row' data-href='my-page.com/user/123'>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></td>
    <td>{{ member.getFornamn }} {{ member.getEfternamn }}</td>
    <td>{{ member.getEmail }}</td>
    <td>{{ member.getTel1 }}</td>
    <td>{{ member.getPostadress }}</td>
    <td>{{ member.getPostnr }}</td>
</tr>
```

Nothing is happening.
If i change to this: window.location.href = 'www.google.com'; it's working so I know **WERE** the problem is...

What am I missing?

**Edit:** 
Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/0MBucaxR1fDpYZjZRLHc?p=preview

For some reason above doesn't work for me. If I use this it works:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location.href = '**any link at all**';
    });
});
```

But when i change to this my console log don't even recognize my click...??

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).data('href');
    });
});
```

Comment: Does `data-href` attribute setted dynamically?

Comment: try $(this).attr('data-href'); and $('body').on('click', '.clickable-row', function() { ..your code here.. });

Comment: Console log `$(this).data('href')` to ensure it is what you think it should be.  Also maybe you need `http://` at the start.

Comment: @mohammad : Not now but it will be when it's working.

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://plnkr.co/edit/0MBucaxR1fDpYZjZRLHc?p=preview

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz tried that also and it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try @AlanP. 's recommendation? What is href attr on log? And try putting "http://" + "my-page.com/user/123". And maybe you can try assing this window.location instead of window.location.href.

Comment: @AlanP.I edited above. As long as I have a string as arg for window.location it works so I don't think http:// is the problem.

Comment: @AlanP. I have console log and it was correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {

        thisdata = $(this).attr('data-href');
        console.log(thisdata);

        window.location.href = thisdata;
    });
});
```

And the console gave me the correct answer.

I noticed that my actual table looked like this:

`<tr class='clickable-row' data-href='URL://my-page.com/user/123`'>

So by removing the **URL://** it works now.

Thand you for your help!

Comment: Actually, I bet it's the `.data('href')` that is the culprit. Using jQuery's `data()` method will only get what has been present at page-load or what has been specifically set with `data()`. In my experience, using `.attr('data-href')` for getting is much more reliable: it handles elements injected after page-load (i.e. AJAX) as you would expect, and also allows for CSS rules.